# difference between erdas and erdas imagine

Tags: discussion, tags

I was just posting a question on erdas and as I was tagging it I saw erdas and erdas imagine. I thought they both were same. Is there a difference?

Pardon my ignorance.

Comment: There's nothing the matter with ignorance (a state of not knowing something), because--unlike other negative human conditions like arrogance or pride--it can easily be cured. In this case, consult http://geospatial.intergraph.com/products.aspx for instance. But the question really is whether it's useful to have two tags that make such a fine distinction. That's worth looking into.

Comment: Oh right Erdas is the main software and IMAGINE is one of their products, is that correct?

Comment: It seems to be something like that. It looks like Intergraph acquired ERDAS and has made its products into a brand name or line of related products. "Imagine" is the particular image-processing software ERDAS has long been known for.

Comment: Oh k thanks @whuber

Comment: @Sam007 You might find this useful ;-) http://www.google.com/insidesearch/landing/powersearching.html

Comment: Thanks @R.K. that will surely help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ERDAS was the name of the product before it was renamed into ERDAS Imagine. Some people still call it just Erdas, so those 2 tags came from this i'd say.

Also on the wiki it says that Erdas inc. rebranded to Intergraph Geospatial